# How to make sure a long running Java thread never die

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I have a long running thread that does house keeping tasks. The failing of the thread is hard to detect given the system will not be immediately affected. I want to make sure this thread never dies. My understand is as long as the code catches everything (Throwable), it will never die. Here is the sample code:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // house keeping logic
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // do not do anything
    }
}
```

Is my understanding correct? Is there a better way hosting long running background tasks? I know ScheduledExecutorService can schedule tasks periodically but if the task needs to  keep checking some resource, it is probably more efficient to just put everything in a while loop.

Comment: The thread will die along with the entire JVM in a few cases (e.g. `OutOfMemoryError`); there is no such thing as an immortal process. It depends on the resource, but putting everything in a `while` loop is almost certainly **not** the most efficient way.

Comment: What kind of application is this thread running in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have guaranteed long-running thread. However, you can have re-spawning logic if something goes wrong with your thread.

What you can do is have a watcher that will check if the thread is running every x mins.

Please note, the watcher will fail if JVM is shut down or crashed. If you want to re-start the thread even if JVM shuts down, you need to have external monitoring. For this, you can use tools such as [supervisord.](http://supervisord.org/)

```
public class LongRunningThread extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean IS_RUNNING = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (IS_RUNNING) {
            try {
                // actions
                this.houseKeep();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private void houseKeep() {
        // housekeeping logic here
    }

}

class ThreadWatcher {
    private Thread threadToBeWatched;

    public ThreadWatcher(Thread threadToBeWatched) {
        this.threadToBeWatched = threadToBeWatched;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/1 * * * *")
    public void checkStatus() {
        if (!threadToBeWatched.isAlive()) {
            // Logic to restart the thread.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the housekeeping logic includes some tasks that could be classified as periodic tasks ( e.g check the connectivity to some service once per 20 seconds ) - then you'd be better off with [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimerTask.html)

Some [example could be of help](https://www.journaldev.com/1050/java-timer-timertask-example).

If something (anything short of OOM) happens in the TimerTask - it won't affect the timer that is responsible for task scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

I would strongly recommend using `ScheduledExecutorService` or some other equivalent feature that may be provided by any tools or framework you are using (e.g. `@Scheduled` in Spring). There are lots of considerations in these situations that are not immediately obvious, and a well established and maintained library will deal with these.

Second, it is uncommon to poll for changes in this manner without some kind of delay. A typical scenario might require you to, for example, close connections with machines that haven't responded in 1 minute. For this sort of loop, you don't need to be constantly checking, as the above loop will do. At the very least, you should include a call to `Thread.sleep()` to prevent excessive resource use. (This is another issue that `ScheduledExecutorService` deals with nicely).

Finally, you should include some way to gracefully exit the loop when your application terminates. A simple `boolean running = true;` on the class would suffice, and you then change your loop to: `while (running) {...}`. When you want to exit, simply set `running = false;` and your loop will exit.

Comment: *catching all `Throwable` will only catch checked exceptions* Huh?!

Comment: My mistake, clearly a late night. I'll edit my answer